# AWS SCT Postgres RDS to Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-dms, aws-sct

I want to create table in Redshift equivalent to the one in Postgres RDS.

I am trying to do the schema conversion from Postgres RDS to RedShift RDS. But the SCT (AWS Schema conversion Tool) doesn't provide the interface to map Postgres to Redshift. Postgres is only coming up under OLTP but Redshift is OLAP.

Comment: Have you tried just running your schema scripts directly? I haven't found too many things needing changing when running scripts from local postgres on remote redshift instance. The only thing that can (but doesn't have to immediately) be added is distkeys and sortkeys.

Comment: Thanks @AdamOwczarczyk  
Couldn't find any tools and AWS SCT only does OLTP to OLTP and OLAP-OLAP conversion.  Postgres DDL worked as it is on Redshift, so was lucky this time. Probably this can be manually worked around or can be scripted if we are aware of the changes.